# RSelenium timeout on Windows 7

Tags: r, selenium

I successfully run Rselenium on my work computer but following the same process in my home computer have been a pain.

The steps I have followed are:

- Install wdman and Rselenium in R.
- Download the file selenium-server-standalone-3.5.1.jar and copy into the bin folder (C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin)
- Download Chrome Driver and copy into the bin folder.
- Updated Java (Version 8 Update 144)
- I tried also changing the ports and deactivating Antivirus and Firewall.

After running this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
library(wdman) 
library(RSelenium)

selServ <- selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"))
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 9040L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
```

> Error in checkError(res) : 
>     Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I have followed before running your R code on my Win7 64bit machine:

- Install wdman and Rselenium in R.
- Download the file selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) and copy into my working directory
- Download Chrome Driver 2.31 [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.31/) (chromedriver_win32.zip) and copy chromedriver.exe into my working directory.
- Update Java

Then, I ran the following code:

```
library(wdman) 
library(RSelenium)

selServ <- selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"))
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4444L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
```

and got:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$acceptSslCerts
[1] TRUE

$applicationCacheEnabled
[1] FALSE

$browserConnectionEnabled
[1] FALSE

$browserName
[1] "chrome"

$chrome
$chrome$chromedriverVersion
[1] "2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8)"

$chrome$userDataDir
[1] "C:\\Users\\msandri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir7408_28639"


$cssSelectorsEnabled
[1] TRUE

$databaseEnabled
[1] FALSE

$handlesAlerts
[1] TRUE

$hasTouchScreen
[1] FALSE

$javascriptEnabled
[1] TRUE

$locationContextEnabled
[1] TRUE

$mobileEmulationEnabled
[1] FALSE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$networkConnectionEnabled
[1] FALSE

$pageLoadStrategy
[1] "normal"

$platform
[1] "Windows NT"

$rotatable
[1] FALSE

$setWindowRect
[1] TRUE

$takesHeapSnapshot
[1] TRUE

$takesScreenshot
[1] TRUE

$unexpectedAlertBehaviour
[1] ""

$version
[1] "60.0.3112.101"

$webStorageEnabled
[1] TRUE

$id
[1] "03c8ac610167a0572dafb357e4f4f288"
```

I hope it can help you.